# Creating a NSDictionary as Int:String out of an plist-file

Tags: dictionary, swift, plist

I created a plist-file which contains *ints as keys* and *strings as values*. now I want to create a dictionary out of it:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myPlist", ofType: "plist")
let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!) as [Int:String]
```

... but the app crashes. however, if I declare it as a [String:String] it works. but I need the key as an int.

I can't find any mistake within the plist.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no implicit cast or conversion from `String` to `Int` in swift, so you have to do that manually by declaring a new dictionary and inserting elements via a `for` loop:

```
var plist = [Int : String]()
for (key, value) in dict {
    if let index = (key as? String)?.toInt() {
        if let value = value as? String {
            plist[index] = value
        }
    }
}
```

The first `if` makes sure that the key can be converted to `Int`, whereas the second checks that the value is actually a `String`.